# Is there any differences between send and dsend in SimGrid?

Tags: java, simgrid

Is there any differences between send and dsend in SimGrid, except except blocking/ non-blocking function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dsend` is a non-blocking *detached* send. If you look for a non-blocking send, then that's `isend`. The difference is that where you absolutely have to do `MSG_comm_wait()` or `MSG_comm_test()` to finish a communication that were started with `isend` (the data transfer will not occur unless you do so), you cannot interact with the communication started with `dsend`.

The concept of detached communications is inspired from detached threads, so it may help to read about it on the Internet.